# Show that if $x_n = O(a_n)$ and $y_n = O(a_n)$, then $x_n + y_n = O(a_n)$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that if $x_n = O(a_n)$ and $y_n = O(a_n)$, then $x_n + y_n = O(a_n)$.

seems so easy but its really stumping me. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* The result follows immediately from definition and triangle inequality: If there are some $M_{1}, M_{2}$ such that $|x_{n}| \leq M_{1}|a_{n}|$ and $|y_{n}| \leq M_{2}|a_{n}|$ for large $n$, then $|x_{n}+y_{n}| \leq |x_{n}| + |y_{n}| \leq (M_{1}+M_{2})|a_{n}|$ for large $n$.